# Showing main menu and child menu in diffent places in a same page

Tags: menus, child-pages

This question may sound a bit novice, but I am facing a problem. I have a menu structure like this:

```
Home
About
-History
-kontact
Posts
-Category1
-category2
```

For design purpose, I have 2 different menu section - 1. main menu, 2. submenu. For showing the main menu, I am using this:

```
<nav role="navigation">
<?php
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location'    => 'primary', 
        'container'         => false,
        'depth'             => 1,
    ) 
);
?>
</nav>
```

And for showing child menu:

```
<nav class="submenu"><ul>
<?php
$current_page_id = get_the_id();
$current_pages_parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( get_the_id() );
get_child_menu($current_page_id, $current_pages_parent_id);
?>
</ul></nav>
```

Function "get_child_menu" looks like this:

```
function get_child_menu($current_page_id, $current_pages_parent_id){
    $cpi = ($current_pages_parent_id == 0) ? $current_page_id : $current_pages_parent_id;
    $args = array(
        'child_of'     => $cpi,
        'depth'        => 1,
        'echo'         => 1,
        'post_type'    => 'page',
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'title_li'     => '',
    );
    wp_list_pages( $args );
}
```

I have not added any of the child pages in wordpress menu editor, since I am not using the hierarchical menu structure here.
 
It works fine (though I feel uncomfortable with this solution). It does not work for the single post page. When I go to the single posts page, the "get_child_menu" function does not work since the parent_page_id is "0". As a result I don't get child menus there. As I mentioned before, I am not a fan of this total solution, how can I create a better solution to achieve this? 2 different menu section (main and child) and works for all (both pages and posts). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe `$current_pages_parent_id == 0` is the same as false or null. Not sure if this is the solution, but try ` $current_pages_parent_id === 0` to ensure that the condition is the integer 0.

Comment: Oh you mean it won't work because your ternary operator checks for parent ID of zero? It looks like `wp_get_post_parent_id()` returns false so you should check for 'false' instead of integer 0 if you're trying to determine if there is a parent.

Comment: Another thing to consider is your `post_type ` query argument is only set for the 'page' post type. If you need to include the 'post' post type, use an array to include both. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters

Comment: Thing is that, in a single post page, I cannot get the parent page id. Because it is a post. For example if I click a post in "Category1" page, after coming into that post page, I cannot determine the parent page (From where I came).

Comment: Are you saying it won't get the parent ID on post type "post"? You are referring to it as both a "post" and a "page", but as far as the `post_type` argument of your query is concerned, these are two different things. Currently, your query will only return the "page" post type in `wp_list_pages`.

Comment: My menus are mixed up with both pages and posts. In this case, "Posts" is also a page which contains the post categories. And subpages of "Posts" (Category1, Category2) are also pages. In those pages there are posts. If I click one of the posts in there and go to the post's detail page, then i cant really determine the parent.

Comment: Maybe you could make a child category for pages of each parent category so you have more control over how they are displayed with `wp_list_categories` http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Only_Show_Children_of_a_Category

Comment: Ok, I created the menu from admin (exactly how it should look) and solve the design with CSS. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Awesome news. Please post your solution as an answer.